# SQL pagination - how to increment page number

Tags: sql, pagination, increment

This is a really stupid question, and it probably has a simple answer. I'm working on a SQL query and I'm seeing a lot of queries that use pagination like this:

```
declare @RowsPerPage int = 20,
@pageNumber int = 1,
@count int = 0

SELECT 
    OrderID,
    Count(*) Over() AS TotalRows
FROM Location.Orders
ORDER BY OrderID
OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage) ROWS
         FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;
```

They all use a variable called `@PageNumber` or something along those lines. I get what it does - it's getting the amount of rows to offset by multiplying the number of pages by rows per page.

What I don't understand is how is `@PageNumber` being incremented each time the next page is loaded?

Obviously there's a really simple explanation since no-one seems to need to mention it, but I'm stumped.

(In case it's applicable, I'm working in Linnworks and don't know which backend database is being used)

Comment: It won't increase though, it will show the 20 records from  `pagenumber = 1`.  [Here](https://database.guide/pagination-in-sql-server-using-offset-fetch/) is a example for Pagination Loop (Example 6)

Comment: @venky__ thanks, that's pushed me onto the right track